# How to colorize a 3D image

Tags: graphics3d, image-processing, color, image3d

I have a 3D image where the values are in {1/4, 2/4, 3/4, 4/4} and its size is {134, 134, 67}. I used Image3D to display it. However, I am wondering if there is a possibility to colorize the image by 4 different colors. I have an image like this [3d image](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Files/MedianFilter.en/O_3.gif)

[image: exemple].

`Image3D[image3D,ColorFunction->Hue]` gives

I need just to use a kind of `Opacity[]` function to see all points.
[image: result]

Comment: You've seen `Colorize[]`?

Comment: J.M. -- I don't think Colorize works for 3D... only 2D.

Comment: @bills it does take a `ColorFunction` option though.

Comment: Possibe duplicates: ([72363](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72363/image3d-with-values-outside-of-the-range-0-1)) and ([38305](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38305/what-is-the-default-colorfunction-for-image3d))?

Comment: @blochwave, I have edited my question

Comment: Use `ColorFunction -> "HueOpacity"` instead of `ColorFunction -> Hue`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about adding `ColorFunction' to your Image3D:

```
m = RandomChoice[{1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1}, {4, 4, 4}];
Image3D[m, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image]

Play with the Colorfunction to get different color schemes:

```
m = RandomChoice[{1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1}, {5, 10, 10}];
Image3D[m, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image]